# Vector Question I Cannot Answer!

Tags: vectors

I have this question about vectors that I can't quite understand how to do. I can answer part (a) but not (b) or (c), if anyone can help I would be more than grateful!

A particle starts from rest and moves with constant acceleration. After 5 seconds its
velocity is (3
             4) ms-1 (this is a vector).

(a) find the acceleration of the particle.

(b) find the displacement vector of the particle from its starting position after 5 seconds.

(c) find the distance travelled by the particle after 5 seconds.

Comment: Did you mean $\vec v=3i + 4j$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan yes I did :)

Answer (score 1):

As acceleration is constant and the particle starts from rest, $\vec v=\frac 35ti+ \frac 45tj$. You can calculate displacement using integration from $t=0$ to $t=5$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the correct answer so that the system removes it from the unanswered questions list.